# grub2 starts after grub rescue while trying to save my debian server

Tags: linux, debian, grub

After screwing up in Debian Jessie (accidentally run rm -R /) my server stopped responding and I decided to reboot. After rebooting grub rescue started and tried to fix it by running the following commands:

```
set root=(hd0,1)
set prefix=(hd0,1)/usr/lib/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

No errors so far, after running "normal" grub2 promps up. So I'm not sure what to do here because I don't want to lose my files.

In grub2 if I run ls (hd0,1)/ I recognize my server and files. What are the following steps to boot debian as normal again?

Comment: Some of your files will be there. You may not have enough left to actually boot the system. You probably will need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. confirm that everything in /etc/grub.d and /etc/default/grub is correct

   run update-grub2 to recreate /boot/grub/grub.cfg

   grub-install /dev/sda (or other as appropriate)